# Did anything specific happen on the 16 or 22 March 1992 passes of a Lacrosse I surveillance satellite over Tehran?

Tags: history, military, international-politics, reconnaissance-satellite

After reading the question [Predicting non-Iridium flares and Why NOSS satellites flare?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/39103/12102) I found the following page linked in Wikipedia's  [Naval Ocean Surveillance System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naval_Ocean_Surveillance_System).

The h2g2 (The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy: Earth Edition) post [Naval Ocean Surveillance Satellites - a 'UFO'](https://h2g2.com/edited_entry/A2265815) created in 2004 and updated in 2015 discusses amateur observation of NOSS satellites.

Near the end is this somewhat cryptic passage:

> It is a misconception that satellites can operate today in a totally covert manner. The technology needed to track and counter/disable is available and inexpensive. There is easy access to a worldwide network of amateur satellite observers. Complete with a skymap and a PC, anyone can plot and predict the movement of satellites. **To detect and track means that the hardware has to be available, for a technology that is being constantly produced it is easily available if a nation can afford the cost. Most Second and Third World nations can afford it, eg India.**
>
> **An example of this is** ***a Lacrosse I surveillance satellite over Tehran being targeted for the 16 March, 1992, and again on the 22 March, 1992.*** **With the knowledge of the satellite's trajectory, elevation, and height it would have been possible for Iran to fire a missile to knock out the satellite.** Such anti-satellite measures are a growing security threat to the US and there is a need for projects to involve formations of satellites so as to prevent any attack on the satellites from rendering their work useless. Another added problem here is that there is a need for a rapid satellite replacement, so that surveillance and intelligence gathering can continue, the US has none employed.

**Question:** Did anything specific happen on the 16 or 22 March 1992 passes of a Lacrosse I surveillance satellite over Tehran? Or are these dates just a pair of red herrings? I don't even understand what was targeting what. *Did the satellite's orbit target Tehran, or did Tehran target the satellite* for example/

Comment: My guess would be the original words were near a picture similar to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lacrosse_(satellite)#/media/File:Lacrosse3_19032011_1.jpg, with the current webpage being assembled from some form of slideshow or presentation (or possibly several, one on UFOs and one on ELINT) and all the picture(s) being cut. Internet archive only goes back to 2014, the 2004 version of the page might have more context.